# jQuery chaining different events and elements to trigger the same function

Tags: jquery, events

Is there a way to chain multiple events and elements to trigger the same function?
So in the example below I have one button and one dropdown. How can I chain their respective events to call the same function.

```
$("#btnOne #dropdownOne").on('click change', function () {
    someFunction();

}
```

currently I have to do the following:

```
$("#btnOne").on('click', function () {
    someFunction();

}


$("#dropdownOne").change(function () {
    someFunction();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use a comma to separate the selectors:

```
$("#btnOne, #dropdownOne").on('click change', function () {
    someFunction();    
});
```

Also note that you can pass the reference to `someFunction` to the handler, that way you can determine which element fired the event by using the `this` keyword - should you ever need to:

```
$("#btnOne, #dropdownOne").on('click change', someFunction);
```

Comment: Note that if you do that second thing, `someFunction`'s return value may have an effect on the event (e.g., if it returns `false`).